# Can't find stylesheet files, using Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I'm using Servlets with Tomcat 7 as a server. [My hierarchy is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJglA.jpg)

So when I access '/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js' WebApp can't find this files.

Here is my index.jsp that is in WEB-INF folder.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WebStore</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">WebStore</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Profile
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
       </ul></li>
     </ul>
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
     </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Categories</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Category5</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Brands</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Brand1</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Brand2</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Brand3</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Brand4</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Brand5</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="" class="commodity"> <img class="goodsPhoto" src="images/apple-iphone se 16gb-silver-450x350.png" alt="iPhone">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
       <h5>iPhone SE 16Gb</h5>
       <p class="definition">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque dolorum maiores repellat, autem, veniam incidunt quam
        sed fugit eos expedita, optio.</p>
       <p class="pull-left price">352.15$</p>

      </div>
      <p class="text-right">
       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Add to bucket</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="" class="commodity"> <img class="goodsPhoto" src="images/apple-iphone se 16gb-silver-450x350.png" alt="iPhone">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
       <h5>iPhone SE 16Gb</h5>
       <p class="definition">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque dolorum maiores repellat, autem, veniam incidunt quam
        sed fugit eos expedita, optio.</p>
       <p class="pull-left price">352.15$</p>

      </div>
      <p class="text-right">
       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Add to bucket</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Information</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="info">In bucket: 9</li>
       <li class="info">Money: 15524$</li>
       <li class="info"><a href="#">My profile</a></li>
       <li class="info"><a href="#">My bucket</a></li>
       <li class="info"><a href="#">My wishlist</a></li>

      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Tags</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tag1</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tag2</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tag3</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tag4</a></li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Tag5</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And here is my error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgrMn.jpg)

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebAppTesting</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I click on this error, Chrome redirect me to my index.jsp file. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try looking into your browser's developer tools network tab (F12 in Chrome) to see what the server returned when it was asked for `bootstrap.min.js`?

Comment: I'm sorry) He found my file. But what this error mean? I cannot understand... Why do I have syntax error there?

Comment: Yes, I've looked there, and the status code was 200. When I click on that file, I see the sources of bootstrap, but when I'm clicking on error, he just send me to my index file

Comment: can you show your web.xml?

Comment: I've added web.xml

Comment: I deleted everything from index.jsp, except my links to css and js files. Chrome gives me status code 200, but when I'm trying to open my file he shows me my index file. It happens with css file and js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. As I understood, when I enter localhost, IndexServlet catches the request, then forwards to /WEB-INF/index.jsp. Then, from jsp, I was linking to css file that was located /resources/css/..... I do not know why, but my IndexServlet catches this request and forwards it to index.jsp, that's why I received two identical files.

Another question is: Why servlet caught that request? There was an annotation above servlet such as: ***@WebServlet("/")***. There was no ***"/*"*** to catch all requests.

**Who knows, please, let me know what happened?**

Maybe he recognize this link (/resources/css/...) as PathInfo, that's why he caught all my links